# Find all div elements that contain specific text

Tags: javascript

I found this function here:

```
function contains(selector, text) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function(element){
    return RegExp(text).test(element.textContent);
  });
}
```

I got it from this [link](https://newbedev.com/javascript-queryselector-find-div-by-innertext), it works fine to find the first div element but I don't know how I can make it return all the divs in an array?

Thank you

Comment: Pasting this function into the console of this page and calling `contains(".spacer", "How")` works fine for me. I get 3 divs in an array.

Comment: Not sure why this uses a blind regex. `element.textContent.includes(text)` seems more appropriate to me